# How can I get a hint if current file being edited and not save?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-mac

When I edited a file, there is a small dot on its tabbar showing that it’s been changed. But the small dot keeps showing even I have undone all the changes. It makes that in fact I get no idea if the file unchanged or not.
Is there anyway to get a behavior that if and only the file changed, the small dot shows up? or any other way to check the file status?
[image]

Comment: You can use git for that

Comment: for me the dot disappears when I undo until the last save (Windows).

Comment: @rioV8 oh thanks. It do disappear if I undo using command-z. It’s a bug of vscodevim’s u in normal mode

Comment: with the hint provided by @rioV8 I got a related issue https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/3201